# C++CLIのフォームにUserControlを追加できません

Tags: c++-cli

Visual Studio 2019 で C++CLIのプロジェクトで Windowsフォームを使ったアプリを開発しています。
CLR ユーザーコントロールを追加してコンパイルすると、ツールボックスに「MyUserControl」が追加されます。
これをWindowsフォームに貼り付けようとすると下記のエラーが発生して、フォームに貼り付けることができません。

ツールボックス アイテム 'MyUserControl' の読み込みに失敗しました。アイテムはツールボックスから削除されます。

MyUserControlを貼り付けるには、どうすればよろしいでしょうか？
アドバイスをよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 古い記事もありますがこれらかもしれませんね。[VS2008 ユーザコントロールが使えない？あれ？出来た？だめ？](https://wockey.at.webry.info/201207/article_6.html), [VisualStudioは64bitでユーザーコントロールが設置できない件](http://tanosimiattack.seesaa.net/article/464194957.html) もっと詳しい情報を追記すると助言や回答が得られ易いでしょう。タイトルと本文で使っている技術が何なのか整合性が怪しい感じです。

Comment: sayuri さん回答関連の日本語情報がこちら。[Visual Studio 2012、2013 で Visual C++ の Windows フォーム アプリケーション テンプレートが削除され、新規に作成できない](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/topic/3fb81bfa-20ee-3959-e1d4-c65b1294b200) この情報があったのでWindowsフォームとは.NETのWindows.Formsだと思っていたのですが、全部C++/CLIならsayuriさん回答のように難しいのでは？ それでも全部C++/CLIでやりたいなら、既にVisualStudio2010を持っていればそちらで作っておいて最終調整をVisualStudio2019
で行うとかが考えられます。今VisualStudio2010を保持していないのならMSDN/VidualStudioサブスクリプションでも入手できるかどうか。先々を考えてC#/VB.NETに移行した方が良さそうです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++/CLIでのWindowsフォームデザイナはVisual Studio 2010で搭載されましたが、そのすぐ次のリリースVisual Studio 2012では非推奨とされています。具体的には[Breaking Changes in Visual C++](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/bb531344(v=vs.110)#integrated-development-environment)で

> Although we recommend that you do not create Windows Forms applications in C++/CLI, maintenance of existing C++/CLI UI applications is supported. If you have to create a Windows Forms application, or any other .NET UI application, use C# or Visual Basic. Use C++/CLI for interoperability purposes only.

と説明されていて、既にあるプログラムのメンテナンスには利用できますが、新規にアプリケーションを作るのであれば別の言語の利用を提案しています。
その後、 2013 / 2015 / 2017 / 2019 とリリースされていますが、状況は変わっていません。

エラーが発生し、解決できないのであれば、上記の指示に従い、C#かVisual Basicを選択することをお勧めします。